# Visual Studio error when opening cs|html files

Tags: visual-studio

When opening a Cshtml or an html file i get 2 errors messages:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.
>
> You can get more information by examining the file
> 'C:\Users***\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

```
Log as JsFiddle (to preserve readability):
https://jsfiddle.net/gze67y0u/
```

the interesting part of the log might be this line:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies
```

I tried to google the dll and where it belongs to but had no success.

The other message is may just a side effect of the missing dll:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The Visual Studio language support for Style has not been installed.
> Code-editing IntelliSense will not be available. Markup IntelliSense
> for server controls may not work.

I tried to reset the settings, i tried to repair also an complete reinstall.
What component am i missing?